# Replace words from string with object from array

Tags: php

Currently I'm getting word from a string to replace every element with html code from object array.

Is there a simpler way of writing this? I'm currently having 20 elements, it seems like a long list.

```
class Roles
{
    public $name;
    public $html;
}

$Administrator = new Roles();
$Administrator->name = "Administrator";
$Administrator->html = "<a class='administator'>Administrator</a>";

$Mod_Helpers = new Roles();
$Mod_Helpers->name = "Mod-Helpers";
$Mod_Helpers->html = " <a class='modhelpers'>Mod-Helpers</a>";

$Mod_Coders = new Roles();
$Mod_Coders->name = "Mod-Coders";
$Mod_Coders->html = " <a class='modcoders'>Mod-Coders</a>";

$Mod_Artists = new Roles();
$Mod_Artists->name = "Mod-Artists";
$Mod_Artists->html = " <a class='modartists'>Mod-Artists</a>";

$ModSquad = new Roles();
$ModSquad->name = "ModSquad";
$ModSquad->html = " <a class='modsquad'>ModSquad</a>";

$ModSquad = new Roles();
$ModSquad->name = "ModSquad";
$ModSquad->html = " <a class='modsquad'>ModSquad</a>";

$RoleList = array($Administrator, $Mod_Helpers, $Mod_Coders, $Mod_Artists, $ModSquad);

foreach ($RoleList as $role) {
    $roles = str_replace($role->name, $role->html, $roles);
}
```

Comment: You could maybe make an array and put the names in there, And do a for each loop, that loops through the array,sets them and replace them.